# How to make spring data neo4j support collection type:Map<RelationshipType, Set<NodeBacked>>

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

guys

I am try to wrapper Spring Data Neo4j (SDN version:3.2.3) for developers who are not familiar with SDN. As I do not know how many relationships and relationship types will be owned by domain objects which are created by developers in the future, I need the collection type like Map> annotated by @RelatedTo and @RelatedToVia to support developers to add relationship and relationship type in runtime, which can make SDN transparent to developers.

However, I find that current SDN only support the collection type Set which can be annotated by @RelatedTo and @RelatedToVia to indicate relationship owned by domain object. In this case, developers have to hard code each relationship using collection type Set annotated by @RelatedTo and @RelatedToVia in domain object, which exposes SDN to developers.

Why SDN does not support collection type Map to represent relationship, and how to make SDN support this collection type?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to use a repository with an annotated query method to return this kind of data.

I think this is quite specific, in theory it could be supported with a custom FieldAccessor which could be implemented similar to the other [Relationship-FieldAccessors](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-neo4j/blob/master/spring-data-neo4j/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/neo4j/fieldaccess/RelatedToViaCollectionFieldAccessorFactory.java), but using a separate annotation, or even better a dedicated result type (e.g. `AllRelationships`)

Not sure if you want this, what you gain over the plain Neo4j APIs, i.e. `node.getRelationships()`